# Copying files via scp, from variable, with double quoted names

Tags: bash, scp

I'm trying to deploy my project from my machine to my test server via ssh with scp. My problem is that, before I do deploy everything in the current directory, I have to skip some files and directories. My solution was, to check first if file or directory meets some criteria, add its name to a variable and when my loop finishes, it will copy everything via scp. Then, another problem that I do not understand yet, is that scp doesn't want to copy files with if it is enclosed in double quotes "my-file" within the variable. But I might have files with spaces in the name. From command line, it's ok but not from a variable.

My code is

```
#...
FILES_TO_SEND=""
for file in *
do
    if test -d $file
    then
        if ! test $file = "nbproject"
        then
            FILES_TO_SEND="$FILES_TO_SEND \"$file\"" #or with this '$file'
        fi
    fi

    if test -f $file
    then
        if ! test $file = "changelog.html"
        then
            FILES_TO_SEND="$FILES_TO_SEND \"$file\"" #or with this '$file'
        fi
    fi
done

#--- Sending files ---#
scp -r ${FILES_TO_SEND} "${DEPLOY_SERVER}:${DEPLOY_TEST_ENV}"
#...
```

As response

```
"file1.html": No such file or directory
"file2.c": No such file or directory
"file3.sh": No such file or directory
...
```

PS: I want to make it efficiently, with only on scp call to make only 1 connection. Server is very busy and I don't want to open and close scp connection calling it multiple times.

PS2: I cannot install rsync or something like that. I also don't want to do it via sftp manually every time I deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct (and simpler) way to do this in `bash` (or any other shell with similar support) is to use an array, not a string, to hold the file names.

```
#...
declare -a FILES_TO_SEND
for file in *; do
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then
        if ! [[ $file = "nbproject" ]]; then
            FILES_TO_SEND+=( "$file" )
        fi
    elif [[ -f $file ]]; then
        if ! [[ $file = "changelog.html" ]]; then
            FILES_TO_SEND+=( "$file" )
        fi
    fi
done

#--- Sending files ---#
scp -r "${FILES_TO_SEND[@]}" "${DEPLOY_SERVER}:${DEPLOY_TEST_ENV}"
#...
```

Even simpler: skip the explicit gather-files-in-a-loop approach and use a pattern that matches everything except the forbidden file name and directory name.

```
shopt -s extglob
scp -r !(changelog.html|nbproject) "{$DEPLOY_SERVER}:${DEPLOY_TEST_ENV}"
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly shopt -s extglob does?

Comment: And why array is better in first case?

Comment: Think of the array as an extra level of quoting that works better when it needs to be quoted itself. Usually, quotes embedded in a parameter value do not work to quote whitespace after the parameter is expanded. `shopt -s extglob` is necessary for the `!(...)` pattern, which matches everything *except* what is inside the parentheses.

Comment: I like this solution the most and I found explanation about extglob here http://aplawrence.com/Words2005/2005_05_25.html

Comment: The error you were getting in your question, `"file1.html": No such file...` is because the quotes you added to `FILES_TO_SEND` were being treated as part of the file name, not as operators to protect whitespace.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out but still don't understand why it does that.

Comment: `FILES_TO_SEND` is expanded, but any quotes contained in the value are treated as literal characters, not operators subject to quote removal. `name="\"foo bar\""; ls $name` is equivalent to `ls \"foo bar\"`, not `ls "foo bar"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that to generate a "valid" code:

```
FILES_TO_SEND=$(printf '%s "%q"' "$FILES_TO_SEND" "$file")
```

The %q will do the job of quoting characters such as space, ", etc.

Ex:

```
$ printf '"%q"\n' 'Foo"Ba    '
"Foo\"Ba\ \ \ \ "
```

Or you can try `xargs`:

```
find '(' -type f -not -name 'changelog.html' ')' -or '(' -type d -not -path '*/nbproject/*' ')' -print0 | xargs -r0 scp -r "${DEPLOY_SERVER}:${DEPLOY_TEST_ENV}"
```

The `xargs` would be good in your case, but I could not find a way to tell `scp` that `"${DEPLOY_SERVER}:${DEPLOY_TEST_ENV}"` is the destination rather than the source.

Comment: Interesting. I will try your suggestion as soon as I can and will be back with feedback on that. 10x